# How do I create a hasMany relationship with non-standard foreign keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a Laravel 8 application where a `User` hasMany `Notifications`. The `notifications` table has two required keys: `sender_id` and `recipient_id`. These are both instances of `User`. Here's how I setup the relationship in the model:

`App\Models\User`

```
 public function recievedNotifications()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(Notification::class, 'recipient_id');
 }

 public function sentNotifications()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(Notification::class, 'sender_id');
 }
```

`App\Models\Notification`

```
  public function recipient()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  public function sender()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
```

I want to create two users and properly associate a `Notification` instance for those two users.  I can't quite get the syntax.

I wanted to try something like this but it assigns the incorrect user ids when I manually look at the database entries:

```
$sender = User::factory()->create();
$recipient = User::factory()->create();

$notification = App\Models\Notification::factory()->hasSender($sender)->hasRecipient($recipient)->create();
```

I am not certain if this is a function of:

1: Not having the relationships set up in the PHP Models
2: Not creating the factory the correct way

The  `Notification` factory is defined as the following:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Notification;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class NotificationFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Notification::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //
            'message'        => $this->faker->sentence,
            'is_read'        => rand(0, 1),
        ];
    }
}
```

How do I properly create Notifications with a recipient and sender using factories?

Comment: All of the relationship methods in Laravel (`hasOne()`, `belongsTo()`, `hasMany()` and `belongsToMany()`) can be customized to use different columns from the assumed ones (`id`, `model_id`, etc). Just check the documentation and update your methods as required: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships. `hasOne(Model::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`, `belongsTo(Model::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');`, `hasMany(Model::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`, `belongsToMany(Model::class, 'pivot_table', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`; on `Notifications` model

Answer (score 0):

Why just not use it like this, by assigning the ids from the factory?

```
$sender = User::factory()->create();
$recipient = User::factory()->create();

$notification = App\Models\Notification::factory()->create([
    'recipient_id' => $recipient->id,
    'sender_id'    => $sender->id
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The relationships look good, so I'm leaning towards not using the factory properly.  Factories simply provide default values to use when instantiating new models if you don't provide the attributes explicitly.

You can set these values by supplying an array in the `create()` or `make()` method:

```php
$sender = User::factory()->create();
$recipient = User::factory()->create();

$notification = Notification::factory()->create([
    'sender_id' => $sender->getKey(),
    'recipient_id' => $recipient->getKey(),
]);
```